# React&redux best practice to setup connection to a service only from some containers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new react/redux and trying to follow common practices on structure.

I'm using a backend service to which only a few containers need to connect.

So right now I'm storing the connection state in redux and I include a module in every container which needs to connect it.

Is there a best practice/better way to structure / do it?

It looks something like this:

```
import myConnectionProvider from "modules/myConnectionProvider";
...
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        myConnectionProvider();
    }
    render() { return (...) } 
}
```

in my module:

```
import store from "modules/store";
import {connect} from "reducers/myConnection";
...
export default () => {
  const myConnection = store.getState.myConnection;
  if(!myConnection.isConnecting && !myConnection.isConnected) {
    store.dispatch(connect());
  }
  return;
}
```

reducer:

```
export const CONNECT_REQUEST = "myConnection/CONNECT_REQUEST";
export const CONNECT_SUCCESS = "myConnection/CONNECT_SUCCESS";
export const CONNECT_ERROR = "myConnection/CONNECT_ERROR";

const initialState = {
  isConnecting: false,
  isConnected: false
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CONNECT_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isConnecting: true
            };
        case CONNECT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isConnecting: false,
                isConnected: true
            };
        case CONNECT_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isConnecting: false,
                isConnected: false,
                error: action.error
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const connect = () => {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few tweaks I would advise:

1. Put the logic for whether to connect or not within your action.

   ```
   export const connect = (dispatch, getState) => {
     if(!myConnection.isConnecting && !myConnection.isConnected) {
       dispatch(/* your CONNECT_REQUEST action */);
       myConnection.connect()
         .then(() => {
           dispatch(/* your CONNECT_SUCCESS action */);
           // ...
         });
     }
   }
   ```

   This way you don't need a module and people using your action in the future won't need to remember whether to use the module, they would follow the pattern they do with all other actions.
2. If this connection logic is shared among many components, consider making a [higher order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) to wrap this logic.

If I were you, I would definitely do #1 right now and only do #2 when seeing the connect logic in enough components annoyed me.

Comment: great suggestions, thank you. Still more to think on my side as I've multiple interdependent components connecting so need to structure states in store to avoid timing issues.  But it looks like the direction to go.